# Expenses tracking app integrated with Apple Wallet

Tags: wallet

I have previously used apps to track my expenses, but I wasn't consistent with manually updating it. Is there a way to extract purchases logs from Apple Wallet? Or is there an app that automates logging my expenses?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the main features of the [Apple Card](https://www.apple.com/apple-card/features/). It tracks your spending and is integrated into Wallet.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209489

If you're asking about 3rd party cards stored in wallet, I'm pretty sure the answer is no, although there are apps like [Mint](https://mint.intuit.com/) that will track and categorize your transaction history (but they don't get that data from Apple Wallet)

Comment: Isn't Apple Card still US-only? i.e, of little use to the other 96% of the world's population?